# ERD Modelling tool with Doctrine Support

Tags: database-design, symfony, doctrine-orm, erd

I'm looking for a free or paid software application that I can use for ER modelling.

Since I mostly develop applications using Symfony2/Doctrine, does anyone know about software that has Doctrine support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following comparison is what you're searching:
http://www.orm-designer.com/article/orm-designer-and-mysql-workbench-comparison

Conclusion: both [ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/) and MySQL workbench are able to work with Doctrine.

Since MySQL workbench is free and under the wings of MySQL itself this should be favorable to me.

Comment: However ORM Designer has full support for Doctrine and its ORM properties as opposed to MySQL Workbench. Check out features comparison: http://help.orm-designer.com/en/mysql-workbench.

Comment: @LudekVodicka Most of what you're talking about can be done via the Symfony CLI tools however.  ORM Designer still does not fully handle 1:many and many:many relations with metadata.  It requires hacking some config files to add support, figuring out how to use it, and in my case still using some workarounds to get the data represented as needed.  Don't get me wrong, after trying ORM Designer for a bit, it's a great tool...it's just not worth the pricing currently.  Go with MySQL Workbench + Symfony/Doctrine CLI tools.

Comment: @BrettThomas As I've tried to explain you in our email conversation, ORM Designer/Skipper supports metadata (including very complex ones) for any model object (http://help.skipper18.com/en/extending-orm-attributes). 

What you call "hacking" is common XML customization. On our support site there is detailed documentation and a lot of examples. Also we're offering help with customization to new users as well as we offered to you.

Simply it's not possible to provide such freedom of customization via GUI tools like XML files offer and that's why we decided to use XML (and our users agree).

Comment: @Ludek, your software does not actually truly support those relationships, it requires essentially hacking/modding the software and then doing some workarounds to make things work (which gives you code that is different than if you would have done it normally writing it yourself).  My issue is not with the software, it's the pricing; the enterprise level price tag doesn't match the junior developer feature set; your software is harder to use than the framework itself for anything complex.  You took offense to me explaining why I would not buy your software after multiple emails begging me.

Comment: @LudekVodicka While your documentation may be clear to you, it's not super clear to your customers.  It's clear from reading the docs that English is not your native tongue (don't get me wrong, I commend you for knowing more than one language) and can be somewhat difficult to figure out what needs to be done for the end user.  The sections on customizations seemed to focus more on tutorial type steps to follow an example, rather than showing what's going on behind the scenes.  I was still left with questions because my use cases are more complex than your examples, requiring lots of guessing.

Comment: Agree, the product is overpriced! I could spend 50 eur on this, but not 295 eur

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/).

I always use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) and then [import](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) my database schema into doctrine entities. This let me fine-tune my indices better that way.

Comment: This is the wrong approach when working with the ORM, and it causes more headaches and mistakes than what you'd imagine. ORM-first should be the development approach, where indexes and optimizations only come at a later stage. Do not import your schema repeatedly: the ORM was never meant to be used like that and it will bite you back.

Comment: I can see your point, but the guy asked for an ER-modeling tool. Never had a problem tough :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not interest you directly, and is probably not really fitting your current development cycle either, but I think it's a good approach to avoid code generation wherever possible.

I'm currently developing the modules integration of Doctrine ORM with ZF2, and we got to build a tool that creates on-the-fly graphs of your entities relations:

[image: UML Diagram generated from Doctrine 2 Entity metadata]

(please don't take the graph as a good example)

With this approach, you write entities first, then mappings (annotations/xml/yaml/php) and there you got your schema (displayed by your application). I'm considering pushing this to doctrine/common directly, so it may be available in the DoctrineBundle soon.

Comment: @nord_ua it is already bundled with `DoctrineORMModule` for ZF2

Comment: Any chance you can port it in Symfony 2? :)

Comment: @nord_ua I am working on a new component that could be used with sf2 - not quite there yet :(

Comment: That's pretty cool.  While it doesn't directly affect who model the db first and then generate as much code as possible), I definitely see a lot of applications for it in the tools we are currently lacking.

Comment: Any news? Is it available now? thks. m.

Comment: @mario it is still only part of the Doctrine/ZF2 integration: wasn't extracted yet nor will have time to do that soon. Consider picking it up yourself by reverse-engineering the code (can probably simply be copy-pasted)

Answer (score 0):

There's free tool called Pulpo http://www.pulpo18.com/ Also, paid Skipper with the editing support https://www.skipper18.com/